# int Array in a Array of Structs in a Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fibonacci, memoization

I hope I don't get hammered on this site. I am a novice programmer having much difficulty with this concept. I have been tasked with memoizing the fibonacci sequence. A concept which I think I have a descent grasp on but of course the implementation guidelines are as follows which is what is confusing me.

```
typedef struct Memo
{
// dynamically allocated HugeInteger array to store our Fibonacci numbers
struct HugeInteger *F;

// the current length (i.e., capacity) of this array
int length;
} Memo;

typedef struct HugeInteger
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
int *digits;

// the length of the array (i.e., number of digits in the huge integer)
int length;
} HugeInteger;
```

Already as you can see the fibonacci numbers will not be simple "int" but rather they will be numbers stored in an int array so for instance int - 134528 will be in an array like so
int someNumber[6] = {1,3,4,5,2,8}

I have created the memo like so:

```
Memo *createMemo(void)
{
/*
Description: Create and initialize a Memo struct:
1. Dynamically allocate space for a new Memo struct.

2. Within the Memo struct, dynamically allocate an array of INIT_MEMO_SIZE number of
HugeInteger structs. INIT_MEMO_SIZE is defined in Fibonacci.h.

Note: This is an array of actual structs, not pointers to structs. So, you cannot set     the
individual elements of this array to NULL, and you cannot free() them.

3. Once the array is created, initialize memo→length appropriately.

4. Make two calls to HugeInit() to initialize F[0] and F[1] (your two Fibonacci base
cases) within the Memo struct.

5. For all remaining F[i], initialize the digits field to NULL and the length field to 0     to
indicate that F[i] has not yet been memoized.

Panic: If any calls to malloc() fail within this function, call panic() (defined in
HugeInteger.c) with the following string argument: “ERROR: out of memory in
createMemo()\n”.

Returns: A pointer to the new Memo struct.
*/
int i;

//Dynamically allocate new Memo
Memo *newMemo = malloc(sizeof(Memo));

        //Check if malloc failed
        if(newMemo == NULL)
            panic("ERROR: out of memory in createMemo()\n");

//Malloc a newMemo->F struct
newMemo->F = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger *) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE);

        //Check if malloc failed
        if(newMemo->F == NULL)
            panic("ERROR: out of memory in createMemo()\n");

//Initialize the length of the Memo
newMemo->length = INIT_MEMO_SIZE;

//Make two calls to HugeInit to initialize F[0] and F[1] base cases
HugeInit(&newMemo->F[0], 0);
HugeInit(&newMemo->F[1], 1);

//Initialize the rest of F[i] to NULL & length to 0 so I now it's not memoized
for(i=2; i<INIT_MEMO_SIZE; i++)
    {
    newMemo->F[i].digits = NULL;
    newMemo->F[i].length = 0;
    }

//Return the newly created Memo
return newMemo;
}
```

After I create the new Memo I now enter the fibonacci function and this is where my brain fails on me. I implemented my fibonacci function like so:
struct HugeInteger *fib(int n, Memo *memo)

```
{
/*
Description:
Implement a recursive solution that checks whether F(n) has already been memoized and,     if so,
returns F(n) without making any recursive calls. 

1. If n exceeds the bounds of the array in memo, call expandMemo(). For more information
on what parameters to pass to expandMemo(), refer to its function description above.

3. In order to compute and memoize F(n), you must call the HugeAdd() function that is
defined in HugeInteger.c. The function requires F(n - 1) and F(n - 2) to be memoized
already. HugeAdd() will memoize F(n) if you call it correctly (i.e., it will store the     result
in memo).

Returns: The address of the struct within memo that holds F(n). If memo is NULL or n is     less than
0, return NULL without performing any recursive calls and without calling expandMemo().
*/
int i;

//Handle for negative numbers
if(n < 0 || memo == NULL)
    return NULL;

//Handle for index out of bounds
if(n > memo->length)
    expandMemo(memo, n);

//Check Memory if F[n] already exists and return it
if(memo->F[n].digits != NULL)
    return &memo->F[n];

//return the base cases;
if(n < 2)
    return &memo->F[n];
else
{
    //My thought process was to make two recursive calls and then use the provided
 HugeAdd function to add the information together. HOWEVER the HugeAdd function is a 
void function so it does it's thing and returns nothing. basically it takes the two
arrays and adds them index by index like you would on paper. 
The first argument of Huge add is the first HugeInteger to be added, then the second 
argument is the second HugeInteger to be added, and the third argument is the
HugeInteger where you want the result. second problem I see is that temp1 is never
being malloc'd or initialized so as the fibonacci series grows temp1 will need to be
malloc'd accordingly and then it will need to be filled accordingly. I am lost 
completely as to how to implement this. 

    HugeInteger *temp1 = fib(n-1, memo);
    HugeInteger *temp2 = fib(n-2, memo);

    HugeAdd(&temp1, &temp2, &memo->F[n]);
}

return &memo->F[n];

}
```

I am completely lost as how to get the fibonacci numbers into their respective array slots and then push them to the HugeAdd function. The functions I have outlined cannot be changed either I can only create auxiliary function to assist.

I SIMPLY want insight, I understand I must trek through the depths of programming hell alone just like everyone else, I just want a little guidance so I can stop coding garbage for 6 hours at a time only to get absolutely nowhere.

Comment: I'm afraid that Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for general "insight".  Please try to focus your problem down to a specific technical question.  i.e. what is the one issue that is currently causing you problems?  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: sorry your right, I just wanted to be as clear and concise as possible. my problem is that I cannot get the recursive fibonacci sequence to implement properly. But I am just realizing that the fib function itself is of type HugeInteger so I can actually call the HugeAdd function like so:

Comment: HugeAdd(fib(n-1, memo), fib(n-2, memo), &memo->F[n]). this actually compiles however it gives me some funky output and then says core dumped.

Comment: First make sure you understand how to implement fibonacci without using your large number routines (just use `unsigned long long` or something at first). Then, test your large number routines separately (test the addition operation with various cases, for example). Then try to combine them into one program.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in a comment, you should try to debug the program with a stub implementation of `HugeInteger` first. Once you are convinced the logic of your fibonacci routine is working, then you can try integrating the true `HugeInteger` implementation.  To get you started, here's a simple stub:

```
typedef struct HugeInteger {
    unsigned long long digits;
    int length;
} HugeInteger;

void HugeInit (HugeInteger *h, unsigned long long val) {
    h->digits = val;
    h->length = 1;
}

void HugeAdd (const HugeInteger *a, const HugeInteger *b, HugeInteger *c) {
    assert(a->length);
    assert(b->length);
    assert(!c->length);
    c->digits = a->digits + b->digits;
    c->length = 1;
}

void HugePrint (const HugeInteger *a) {
    assert(a->length);
    printf("%llu\n", a->digits);
}
```

One other pointer. In your `createMemo()` routine, you don't allocate your `F` array properly:

```
//Malloc a newMemo->F struct
newMemo->F = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger *) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE);
```

The `F` member of `Memo` is a `HugeInteger *`, so, you want to allocate `sizeof(HugeInteger) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE` instead.